# React useState hook with array

Tags: reactjs

I want make something like this.

- When user clicks button, then item should be appended to array.
- If user again clicks the button again, then item should be removed from array.

What is the easy way of doing this?

```
  const [state, setState] = useState([])
  const [remove, setRemove] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = e => {
    if(!remove) {
      setRemove(true)
      setState(prev => [Date.now()])
    }else{
      setState(prev => prev.pop())
    }
  }


  return(
    <div>
    {JSON.stringify(state)}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I click the button initially it works as expected. After that, when I try to remove element from the array it shows a weird behaviour. What's wrong?

Comment: `setRemove(false)` needs to be done in the else part also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` needs to copy `prevState` first, and then modify it.

You can do as the following:

```js
const {useState} = React;
const Root = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [remove, setRemove] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = e => {
    if(!remove) {
      setRemove(true);
      setState(prev => [Date.now()]);
    }else{
      const newState = [...state];
      newState.pop();
      setState(newState);
      setRemove(false);
    }
  }


  return(
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(state)}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  )
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Root />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```